# function to execute avoiding any other click event in between

Tags: jquery, html, css

On div click event i wish to disabled click event for images how to do this? i tried unbinding but it seems it only work if event is bind()??

```
$(div).click(function ()
{
//disabled click for images while function Executes 

});
```

Comment: "while function Executes " ? What do you mean ? You can't receive a click event while your function executes.

Comment: @dystroy, you can if your function is executing asynchronous stuff (AJAX requests, Animations implemeneted using setTimeout/setInterval, …)

Comment: @dystry actualy i have div on top of image. on click of div i am rotating div , when user again clicks on div while it is fliping ,then image clicked function is called ... so i want to disabled image click for some time eg. 1000 milisec

Comment: @CBroe no, you won't receive any event until you release control. What you may have is event generated, not received.

Comment: @CBore you are right i am using set-time out function inside div click function  for flip and changing div color after fliping

Comment: @dystroy, yes you will if you are using something that results in an _asynchronous execution_, like withs using timeouts.

Comment: To disable event handling for a time, the simplest is simply to use a boolean variable and to test in your event handler.

Comment: before time out is completes and user clicks then images click is getting called... i cant reduce settime out value as i it takes that much time to flip after that i change div color

Comment: @CBroe Then that's not "while function executes"...

Comment: @destry how to use use boolean ??

Comment: @dystroy – yeah, not from a technical point of view – but from the user asking here that seems to be what was meant. And I agree, just setting some flag _“while the function executes”_ ;-) and check for that flag in other event handlers before they do anything is the easiest way to do something like this (in a low complexity environment).

Comment: @simfiza I tried to explain in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this :

```
var clickEnabled = true;
$(img).click(function (){
   if (!clickEnabled) return;
   // do your stuff
});

$(div).click(function (){
  //start animation
  clickEnabled = false;

  setTimeout(function(){
     //end animation
     clickEnabled = true;
  }, 666);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var areWeAllowedToDoStuff = true;

$(div).click(function () {
  areWeAllowedToDoStuff = false;
  $.start_whatever_animation(
    …, // additional animation parameters
    function() { // callback for when animation has finished
      areWeAllowedToDoStuff = true;
    }
  );
});

$("image").click(function() {
  if(!areWeAllowedToDoStuff) {
    return;
  }
  // do other stuff here
});
```